# Limiting speech recognition choices in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, speech-recognition, speech

I want to know if there is a way to limit the windows speech recogition library to a small library containing only a few words?

I tried makeing a voice operated program with a few words, but when i added words that was hard for the computer to recognice (Like names) it offen recogniced the name as another word. That's why i want to add a spesified dictionary like a list of names.

Eks: Sondre, Robert, Bob

And when saying a name, the program will only check if one of the 3 words where recogniced

Comment: You can use a Grammar object and a GrammarBuilder object to have a subset of options for a specific word or phrase.  See MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this code below for my previous projects that I did using Kinect camera.
I have limited the phrases {faster,slower,stop..} and build up a grammer. I hope it will answer your question

```
    private void initSpeech()
    {
            // You need to change here if you are not using kinect camera 
            RecognizerInfo ri = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers().Where(r => r.Id == "SR_MS_en-US_Kinect_10.0").FirstOrDefault();
            if (ri == null)
            {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not locate speech recognizer. Ensure you have the Kinect Speech SDK/runtime/MSKinectLangPack_enUS installed.");
            }

            sr = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id);
            //Phrases that will be recognised added
            Choices phrases = new Choices();
            phrases.Add(
                "faster", 
                "slower", 
                "stop", 
                "invert y",
                "music volume",
                "effects volume",
                "okay");
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            //adding our phrases to the grammar builder
            gb.Append(phrases);
            // Loading the grammer 
            sr.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));
    }
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for! Not gonna use a kinect but i'll test out your code as soon as i can. Thanks a lot for the help!